# Pointer to interface object gives segmentation fault

Tags: objective-c

Just started programming in Objective C...

This code gives me a segmentation fault. What's wrong with it?
I know for sure it has something to do with "Instruction". The array is working fine.

Instruction.h:

```
    #ifndef romo_objectice_c_Instruction_h
    #define romo_objectice_c_Instruction_h
    #endif

    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    typedef enum direction {north, south, west, east} Direction;
    @interface Instruction:NSObject
        @property Direction dir;
        @property unsigned int distance;
    @end
```

ViewController.m:

```
    #import "Instruction.h"
    #import "ViewController.h"
    @interface ViewController ()
    @end
    @implementation ViewController
    @synthesize instructionList;

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    instructionList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    //THE FOLLOWING CODE CAUSES THE SEGMENTATION FAULT
    Instruction *i;
    Direction d = north;
    i.distance = 1;
    i.dir = d;
    [instructionList queuePush:i];
}
```

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Learn how to get the exception stack trace, to identify the point of failure.

Answer (score 0):

You have no `@implementation` for `Instruction`, which you need. You also don't create an instance before you start trying to use the `i` variable.

I'm not sure what `queuePush` is but that could also be causing you issues...

Comment: OK, I'm assuming this is how I create an instance: Instruction *i = [[Instruction alloc] init];

Could you show me what the header file would like with @implementation?

Comment: It's actually not clear that you don't have an `@implementation` for `Instruction`. The two files shown are Instruction.h and ViewController.m. The implementation of `Instruction` would normally be in Instruction.m, which wasn't shown. Assuming that exists and has the normal stuff in it, the failure to create an instance of `Instruction` and make `i` point to it may be the only problem. And, yes, the snippet you showed in your above comment is how you would instantiate an instance of `Instruction`.

Comment: Thanks.
I don't have Instruction.m 
Is it necessary to have Instruction.m? I don't plan to have any functions in Instruction. Just instance variables.

Comment: Yes, you need somewhere for the properties to be synthesised to. It can be an empty `@implementation @end`, but it has to be there.